# How to configure LAN port 1 to work as a WAN port in my wireless router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

I am using TP-LINK WR340G wireless router. It has 1 WAN port and 4 LAN ports

Recently I noticed that my WAN port is not working properly.

So I am planning to configure the router. I want the LAN port 1 to work as a WAN port (Wifi also should work properly).

I found this solution but it is for different router, I couldn't able to find the same settings in my wireless router.

http://ticket.tp-link.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/272/62/how-to-configure-td-w8960ns-lan-port-work-as-wan-porttd-w8960n-work-with-cable-modem

Is it possible to configure my wireless router? If so, How can I do that? I am ready to test in any level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guys!! any answer or comments??

Comment: Your only description of the problem is that it's "not working properly". That's almost useless.

Comment: I have found a [solution](https://www.gargoyle-router.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7285). Different model but the solution used VLAN and switch configuration which can be useful in your case.  Didn't try, though.